# Raise the stackView above the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, view, stack

I have a login screen. In the middle `(X:0, Y:0)` there is a stackView in which there are two text fields. When I want to enter something in the text fields, the keyboard is shown and the stackView is raised, as soon as I enter a character, it falls into place and nothing is visible. Tell me how to make sure that the stackView does not fall when you enter characters in text fields !!

```
  //MARK: Override
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        ///NotificationCenter keyboard
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
         
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
     }

// Extension keyboard SHOW/HIDE
extension LoginViewController {
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var keyboardHeight = CGFloat(0.0)
        
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.conteinerStackView.frame.origin.y  =  keyboardHeight - 100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillHide() {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.conteinerStackView.frame.origin.y = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this problem.

1. Use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

   Codeless drop-in universal library allows to prevent issues of keyboard sliding up and cover UITextField/UITextView. Neither need to write any code nor any setup required and much more.

install using  or see docs

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

2. Using Keyboard Observer

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
   }

   @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
       if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
           self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
       }
   }

   @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
       self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting bottom constraint to the stackView and use it in observer function.

```
@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: Notification)
{
       let keyboardRect: CGRect = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
        
        let keyboardSize: CGSize = keyboardRect.size
        
        bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height + 20
}

 @objc func keyboardWillDisAppear(notification: Notification)
{
        bottomConstraint.constant = 20
}
```